# I created a sorting tool with Angular.js. How can I animate ng-click to create animated transitions when the items are sorted?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am building a personal portfolio site with Angular and decided to build my project sorter using pure Angular, instead of doing it with jQuery. I utilized the filter feature of Angular, and am able to get the projects to sort correctly. However, when I'm going through the ng-animate section, there's no support for ng-click and filters that I can see. I was also not able to get the ng-animate to work on the ng-repeat (when the projects are all displayed.) I basically want cool transitions whenever a new filter is selected. The same type of reactions to clicking a button as what happens here.

https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

What would be the best course of action to handle animating those types of things? Also, does my code look properly done the 'Angular' way?

jsfiddle-

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbitt/tg6oh0g1/6/

HTML -

```
<div id="portfolio" ng-controller="mainController as main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>Portfolio</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="">
          <ul ng-repeat="language in main.languages">
            <li><button ng-click="main.projectSort(language)">{{ language.name }}</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="project in main.projectsToShow">
        <div class="portfolio-projects language-{{ project.reference }}">{{ project.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-color: black;
}

#portfolio .container, #portfolio .container .row {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#portfolio .container .row {
  height: 33.3%;
}

.portfolio-projects{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.language-angular {
  color: blue;
}

.language-ruby {
  color: red;
}

.language-node {
  color: green;
}
```

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('portfolioSorter', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['filterFilter',   function(filterFilter) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.languages = [
    {
      name: 'ALL',
      reference: 'all'
    },
    {
      name: 'ANGULAR',
      reference: 'angular'
    },
    {
      name: 'NODE',
      reference: 'node'
    },
    {
      name: 'RUBY ON RAILS',
      reference: 'ruby'
    }
  ];

  vm.projects = [
    {
      name: 'Tic-Tac-Toe',
      language: 'ANGULAR.JS',
      reference: 'angular'
    },
    {
      name: 'Escrow',
      language: 'RUBY ON RAILS',
      reference: 'ruby'
    },
    {
      name: 'Feed.Me',
      language: 'RUBY ON RAILS',
      reference: 'ruby'
    },
    {
      name: 'Gone-In',
      language: 'NODE.JS',
      reference: 'node'
    }
  ];

  vm.projectsToShow = vm.projects;

  vm.projectSort = function(language) {
    vm.projectsToShow = vm.projects;

    switch (language.reference) {

      case 'all':
        vm.projectsToShow;
        break;

      case 'angular':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'angular');
        break;

      case 'node':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'node');
        break;

      case 'ruby':
        vm.projectsToShow = filterFilter(vm.projectsToShow, 'ruby');
        break;

      default:
        vm.projectsToShow;
    };
  };

}]);
```

Comment: ng-repeat supports animations and there are lots of tutorials and examples around. If animation transitions are available on the class that is being repeated the animation classes of `ngAnimate` will be applied...filters or no filters

Comment: you're trying to animate the `button` inside `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Yes. I want the projects in the lower div's to animate with cool transitions whenever I use ng-click, which activates a filter.

Comment: I want the exact same type of reactions to clicking the buttons as this:

https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

Comment: use `ng-class` then, it supports animations also. Can toggle variables inside click handler to toggle class